# converting setter, getter variable from objective C to swift 2.2

Tags: objective-c, getter-setter, swift2

I am facing issues while converting from Objective C to Swift 2.2.. Can anyone help me..??

Here is the code in Objective C

variables declared as

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger currentViewControllerIndex;
@property (nonatomic, getter = isWrapEnabled) BOOL wrapEnabled;
```

and the variable setting functions in Objective C are

```
- (void)setWrapEnabled:(BOOL)sWrapEnabled {

    wrapEnabled = sWrapEnabled;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}

- (void)setCurrentViewControllerIndex:(NSInteger)curViewControllerIndex {

    [self scrollToViewControllerAtIndex:curViewControllerIndex animated:NO];
}
```

This is how i have written in Swift

```
var tmpWrapEnabled : Bool = Bool()
internal(set) var wrapEnabled : Bool? {

    get {

        return tmpWrapEnabled
    }

    set(newValue) {

        if newValue == true {

            tmpWrapEnabled = newValue!
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}

var tmpCurrentViewControllerIndex : NSInteger = 0
internal(set) var currentViewControllerIndex : NSInteger? {

    get {
        return tmpCurrentViewControllerIndex
    }

    set(newValue) {
        tmpCurrentViewControllerIndex = newValue!
    }
}
```

Comment: `I am facing issues while converting from Objective C to Swift 2.2` Please include your existing attempt (use the [edit] button to edit your question).

Comment: Take a look at the section *Property Observers* in the [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need only the `didSet` observers, for the rest the variable behaves as a normal variable.

```
var wrapEnabled : Bool {
   didSet {
      if wrapEnabled  {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
      }
   }
}

var currentViewControllerIndex : Int {
   didSet {
    scrollToViewControllerAtIndex(currentViewControllerIndex, animated:false)
   }
}
```

Consider that the observers are not called when the initial value is assigned to the variable.